# event.currentTarget changes when I need to use the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

```
onClick: function(event) {
    var clickTarget = event.currentTarget; // clickTarget is clicked element

    this.namePanel.$el.on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
        console.log(clickTarget);  // clickTarget becomes what got collapsed
    });
}
```

I need that to be able to keep what I clicked, so I can use it in that 2nd function, but `event.currentTarget` changes, which messes up my code.

How do I keep that clicked element for the `hide.bs.collapse` listener?

Comment: You've just bound an event handler inside another event handler, that's why it keeps changing.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? When I click the thing, a bootstrap accordion collapses, and I want to wait for it to collapse before I run the code.

Comment: If `on` is a jQuery method, you could do `.one('hide.bs.collapse', {elem : clickTarget}, function(e) {...` and get the element in `e.data.elem`

Comment: So do not bind on click, just bind it globally and use `$(this)` inside to get the element that collapsesd....or unbind the event after it has run or use one.

Comment: @adeneo That doesn't seem to work. `e.data.elem` contains the collapsed element. 

@epascarello I don't want the element that got collapsed. When I click elementA, elementB ends up being collapsed, but I want to click elementA -> wait for elementB to collapse -> run a function that uses elementA.

Comment: What about using var clickTargetId = event.currentTarget.id and later using $("#"+clickTargetId) to access the element?